# Can't load 'survival' in R version 3

Tags: r, reinstall

I have tried a lot in stackoverflow for this question, such as `update.package`, install 'codetools', and some tips in stackoverflow- How should I deal with “package 'xxx' is not available” warning?
but it doesn't work.
The package seems to be installed, but can't be loaded-

```
library(survival) 
## error:package ‘survival’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
```

Comment: It's a recommended package, so it's not available on CRAN but should be pre-installed.  You probably have some old packages in your path.  Results of `.libPaths()` and `sessionInfo()` please?

Comment: Try update.packages(ask=FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE), ref http://www.r-bloggers.com/automated-re-install-of-packages-for-r-3-0/

Answer (score 1):

@John It's amazing! I had used update.packages before, but it didn't work-just now it works!
But there is still an warning -

```
package ‘survival’ was built under R version 3.1.2
```

@Ben Bolker

```
sessionInfo()#R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)#Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
#locale: #[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936 
#[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936   
#[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936 
#[4] LC_NUMERIC=C 
#[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
#attached base packages:#[1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices
#[5] utils  datasets  methods   base #other attached packages:
#[1] survival_2.37-7#loaded via a namespace (and not attached):#[1] tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: it's just a warning, but if you want to get rid of it, update to R version 3.1.2 ...